# Any better alternative to Facade Pattern for a REST API with multiple entities?

Tags: java, spring, rest, design-patterns, facade

I'm developing a REST API with Java 11, Spring Boot and Spring Webflux.

I found myself having 3 different DB entities/documents (I'm using Reactive MongoDb) and therefore 3 repositories, and 3 services.

For the sake of simplicity let's call the entities E1, E2, E3.

I would like to create an API that works with the 3 services, although there is business logic that ties the 3 entities altogether. For example, a findAll on E1, requires to also do a findAll on E2 and then filter the first result based on the second result.

This gets even more complex when saving or updating, for example to save E2 I need to check if E1 exists, then check if there's another instance of E2 with E1's id, and so on and so forth.

My question is, is the Facade pattern a good idea? Is there a better alternative for this kind of scenario?

I considered splitting the architecture in 3 different microservices, one for each entity, but then I would need to aggregate the results and apply business logic at a higher level (either a 4th microservice that calls the other 3 services, or put that logic in an API Gateway) but I'm not sure if it is a good idea.

EDIT:

I'm already aware of the API Gateway pattern. I just think the business logic that ties the entities is too complex and the logic would end up being written in the Gateway itself, and I don't think it would be a good idea. From my understanding the API Gateway should be stateless, act as a proxy, and deal with security and caching. My question is more like: does it make sense to use the Facade pattern in the scope of a single REST Api? Are there better alternatives?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Uhm didn't know that, I saw other questions about design patterns here on Stack Overflow and they weren't removed so I figured my question would be ok I guess. If you would like, why don't you share your thoughts in the meanwhile, maybe you'll be faster than the mods! :D

Comment: @improbable when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat I don't encourage cross-posting, I didn't even suggest that.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with spring-reactive or spring-boot

Comment: Well if this is the wrong place to ask such question and the thread is gonna be closed, then would it even be cross-posting to ask the same question on software engineering? @Thomas I'll change the tags so that they're more accurate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the facade design pattern only concerned with classes/modules or actual API calls too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61870915/is-the-facade-design-pattern-only-concerned-with-classes-modules-or-actual-api-c)

Comment: @jaco0646 Thanks for the reply. No, not really, I'm already aware of the API Gateway pattern. I just think the business logic that ties the entities is too complex and the logic would end up being written in the Gateway itself, and I don't think it would be a good idea. From my understanding the API Gateway should be stateless, act as a proxy, 
and deal with security and caching. My question is more like: does it make sense to use the Facade pattern in the scope of a single REST Api? Are there better alternatives?